# Is it possible to obtain details of previous cron in appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have a cron job in appengine which runs every 5 minutes to check in a datastore if any new entries are created in a particular table based on the creation time of the entry. As i dont want to report the entry twice, i have the below :

I query in the db for the entries that has creation in (CurrentTime, currentTime - 5min). This is supposed to work and it is working in most of the cases.

The problem is there is a slight possibility that the cron does not report  for few entries. This happens because (currentTime - 5) of previous cron and currentTime of next cron are not the same and there is a slight milliseconds of variation. So if an entry is created in this slot, it wont be reported.

I am trying to bypass this issue. One work around  i look for like 6 minutes in my query and that will ensure no entries are missed out but i may need to handle the duplicates which is another task for me.
I can also store in db or somewhere the time of previous cron execution and based on that i can query but the difference might be get added up at some point leading to delay.

Please kindly put any suggestion on how i can achieve this.

Comment: @SaketMittal thanks for your time. I am not sure if the code is anywhere helpful for solving the question. I think all the required info is already provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. add a **boolean flag to each entry** to mark if it has been reported or not. Hence you have to set it if the corresponding entry has been reported.
2. to avoid additional write access **buffer the Keys of the entries you have already reported** somewhere so that the cron job can access them, query for the last 6 minutes in the cron job and check for each entry if its key is in the buffer or not.

Maybe a third option might be to do the reporting stuff when writing to the datastore?

Answer (score 0):

after writting the entries, get by id the last one written and save its timestamp to the db (and cache it in memcache). use this timestamp in your next cron query.

to avoid the get by key (thus slower if you were using async writes) you can instead write your own timestamp and and use that one which is known to you without getting the entities after a write. the disadvantage is that now it takes more storage space and requires more indexes.

to avoid modifying the db at all, just do what you said about querying the last 6 minutes instead. if you set your own key names then you can store just that last key processed and skip until there. but you will need to handle the trickier case when for some reason the last cron failed to run thus you wont find that last written entitiy by lookig back just 6minutes in the past.